# How to prove that the subgradient of a dual function contains the equality constraint for closed and convex function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Apologies for the fundamental question. But I am am just trying to understand the pieces.

Let us consider a minimization problem
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad & f(x) \\
\text{subject to }\quad & Ax = b \ ,\\
\end{align}
where $f(x)$ is closed and convex function, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now, if we write a dual problem
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}_{u \in \mathbb{R}^m} \ g(u) \equiv \text{maximize}_{u \in \mathbb{R}^m} -f^*(-A^T u) - b^T u \ , 
\end{align}
where $f^*$ is a conjugate of $f$.

> Question:
>   How to prove that $Ax-b \in \frac{\partial}{\partial u} g(u)$?

ADD:
I want to understand through the conjugate function (not through the Lagrangian $L(x,u) = f(x) + u^T(Ax-b)$, and then taking the derivative of $L$ w.r.t. $u$ yields the condition that $Ax-b=0$ (or one could equivalently explain through the KKT conditions).

---

Partial attempt:

The subgradient of $\partial g(u)$ can be shown as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} g(u) = A \ \frac{\partial}{\partial u} f^*(-A^T u) - b \ . 
\end{align}

Now how to proceed and prove that the equality constraint exist in the subgradient of $g(u)$?

EDIT: 
For closed and convex function $f$, I can say that $x \in  \frac{\partial}{\partial u} f^*(-A^T u) $. So, $Ax-b \in \frac{\partial}{\partial u} g(u)$. Correct?

Comment: It's quite obvious if you just write down the Lagrangian without using the conjugate and then take the inf over $u$.  You get a $u^{T}(Ax-b)$ term, which has $Ax-b$ as a gradient.  If $Ax \neq b$, then that inf is unbounded.

Comment: I agree with that if you form a Lagrangian $L(x,u) = f(x) + u^T(Ax-b)$, then the gradient w.r.t. $u$ yields $Ax-b=0$. However, I wanted to understand also using the Conjugate.